# Embedding resources in a Mono app

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm attempting to embed some resources in my app using the following commands (run on an Ubuntu box):

```
resgen2 -usesourcepath testResource.resx testResource.resources

gmcs -out:Test.exe -debug -platform:x86 -target:winexe test.cs
     -resource:testResource.resources
```

The compile runs just fine, but when I run the program under Windows I get:

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any
>   resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure
>   "testResource.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Test"
>   at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and
>   fully signed.

Has anybody else had a similar issue?